# Multiple copies of React loaded when using material-ui

Tags: json, reactjs, components, material-ui, ref

I have installed material-ui on my application, and when calling any component from the material-ui I get this error:

`` addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: . ``

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm-run-all --parallel start-message",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:CI": "babel-node tools/testCi.js",
    "test:cover": "npm run test -- --coverage ",
    "test:cover:CI": "npm run test:CI -- --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && opn ./coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
    "analyze-bundle": "babel-node ./tools/analyzeBundle.js"
  },
  "author": "David Shusterman",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "material-ui": "0.18.7",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "react-collapsible": "1.5.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router": "3.0.5",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.8",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-infinite-scroll": "1.0.9",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "15.5.4",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.12",
    "chalk": "2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "coveralls": "2.13.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "2.9.1",
    "eslint": "4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-watch": "3.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "jest-cli": "20.0.4",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "mockdate": "2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "opn-cli": "3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.1",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.5.4",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.0.0",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0",
    "redux": "^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2|ico)$": "<rootDir>/tools/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "stage-0",
      "stage-1",
      "stage-2"
    ],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "presets": [
          "env",
          "react-hmre",
          "stage-0",
          "stage-1",
          "stage-2"
        ]
      },
      "production": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "env",
            {
              "es2015": {
                "modules": false
              }
            }
          ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "transform-class-properties",
          "transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          "env"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:import/errors",
      "plugin:import/warnings"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
      }
    },
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "jquery": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quotes": 0,
      "no-console": 1,
      "no-debugger": 1,
      "no-var": 1,
      "semi": [
        1,
        "always"
      ],
      "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
      "eol-last": 0,
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
      "no-alert": 0,
      "no-lone-blocks": 0,
      "jsx-quotes": 1,
      "react/display-name": [
        1,
        {
          "ignoreTranspilerName": false
        }
      ],
      "react/forbid-prop-types": [
        1,
        {
          "forbid": [
            "any"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "react/jsx-boolean-value": 0,
      "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 0,
      "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
      "react/jsx-indent-props": 0,
      "react/jsx-key": 1,
      "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 0,
      "react/jsx-no-bind": 0,
      "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
      "react/jsx-no-literals": 0,
      "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
      "react/jsx-pascal-case": 1,
      "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
      "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
      "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
      "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": 1,
      "react/no-danger": 1,
      "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
      "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
      "react/no-set-state": 0,
      "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
      "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
      "react/prop-types": 1,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
      "import/extensions": 1,
      "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
      "react/sort-comp": 1
    },
    "globals": {}
  }
}
```

and this is my webpack.config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';

export default {
  resolve : {
    alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
  },
    extensions: [
      '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'
    ]
  },
  devtool : 'eval-source-map', 
  entry : [
    // must be first entry to properly set public path
    './src/webpack-public-path',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js') // Defining path seems necessary for this to work consistently on Windows machines.
  ],
  target : 'web', 
  output : {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins : [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: false, debug: true, noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
      options: {
        sassLoader: {
          includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')]
        },
        context: '/',
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      }
    })
  ],
  module : {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }, {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      }, {
        test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      }, {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      }, {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I will appreciate very single help. I've tried almost everything
- reinstalling nodemodules
- adding externals
- switching dependencies on package.json

please help  :)

Comment: Why are you setting a resolve alias for react? `react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')`  You shouldn't need this

Comment: it's something I've tried to resolve the error. the error occurs with or without it anyhow..

Comment: This happened to me a while back and it was simply a problem with Material-UI and the NPM version I was using and the React version.  Something about Material UI installing a second copy of React if using a version of React < 15. Maybe it's the peerDependencies `"react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0",`  You can read what I believe is a related issue here https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2818